# UVM TB and DUT parameter control

Tags: uvm

Please help to resolve one issue that I am facing with planning my TB.
Let’s assume my DUT has some input port which is parameter, something like:

```
module Multiplier #(parameter WIDTH = 8) (
    input [WIDTH-1:0] addr,
```

Now I want my test to control this WIDTH parameter.
I want the test to randomize the WIDTH parameter, then apply that parameter to DUT. And based on that parameter value my whole testbench will be changed the transaction signals, driver, monitor and so on.
What is the best way to implement this parametric test?

I am thinking to have the WIDTH parameter in test class, and randomize it there. Then assign it to the DUT during instantiation. And for TB,  put the randomize value  in config_db and in agent get it and assign it to config class appropriate parameter.

Thanks
Hayk

Comment: I doubt this is possible. Your `uvm_test` only begins after elaboration, and at this time, all modules have been instantiated already. You would need to set the parameter before that. I would suggest using something like `$urandom` during compilation

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You mean in the top module call use $urandom?

Comment: I believe `$urandom` can only be called during run-time.

Comment: I also agree that this may not be possible. Because in run time there will be a fixed value of `WIDTH`, according to which all the module ports will be created.

Comment: I guess generate statement may help here
If I call urandom, than instaniate the DUT using generate statement

Comment: The `genvar` may need fixed bounds at time of elaboration. I doubt this would work as well

Answer (score 0):

I would generate a random variable in my Makefile (or whatever build/compilation system you are using). Then depending on your simulator, set the parameter from the simulation run command.

**ModelSim:** 
The Parameters value can be passed with ‘vsim’ command in the ModelSim simulator. Assuming we want to supply a parameter value globally to all the modules:

```
-gWIDTH=<random_value>
```

**VCS**

```
-pvalue+hierarchical_name_of_parameter=<random_value>
```

All simulators have an equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! But I would like to use simulator commands as it will make my TB to be dependant on simulator type(( Also Im not sure what simulator will my customer use